# Hadoop - namenode is not starting up

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to run hadoop as a root user, i executed namenode format command `hadoop namenode -format` when the Hadoop file system is running.

After this, when i try to start the name node server, it shows error like below

```
13/05/23 04:11:37 ERROR namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed.
java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:330)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:411)
```

I tried to search for any solution, but cannot find any clear solution.

Can anyone suggest?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you stared your HDFS daemons. Look here it might help http://blog.abhinavmathur.net/2013/01/experience-with-setting-multinode.html

Comment: Thanks Abhinav.. Your link gave me answers..

Comment: why would you format HDFS while the daemons are running??

Comment: Mistakenly did that.. after that only i came to know, i should not do like that..

Comment: @abhinav link is dead, Moved anywhere ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Cool, i have found the solution.

Stop all running server

```
1) stop-all.sh
```

Edit the file `/usr/local/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml` and add below configuration if its missing

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>/app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name/data</value> 
    <final>true</final> 
    </property> 
    <property> 
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>/app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name</value> 
    <final>true</final> 
</property>
```

Start both HDFS and MapReduce Daemons

```
2) start-dfs.sh
3) start-mapred.sh
```

Then now run the rest of the steps to run the map reduce sample given in [this link](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/)

**Note :** You should be running the command `bin/start-all.sh` if the direct command is not running.

Comment: as a reminder, namenode was needed to be formatted for me. `bin/hadoop namenode -format`

Comment: Yup. we can use the command `hadoop namenode -format -force` in case if we face any issue with just `hadoop namenode -format`

Comment: After doing this, even DataNode stopped showing up on JPS :(

Answer (score 28):

DFS needs to be formatted. Just issue the following command after stopping all and then restart.

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

Answer (score 2):

format hdfs when namenode stop.(just like the top answer).

I add some more details.

FORMAT command will check or create path/dfs/name, and initialize or reinitalize it.
then running start-dfs.sh would run namenode, datanode, then namesecondary.
when namenode check not exist path/dfs/name or not initialize, it occurs a fatal error, then exit.
that's why namenode not start up.

more details you can check HADOOP_COMMON/logs/XXX.namenode.log

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the directory you've specified for your namenode is completely empty. Something like a "lost+found" folder in said directory will trigger this error.

Answer (score 0):

hdfs-site.xml your value is wrong. You input the wrong folder that's why is not starting the name node.

Answer (score 0):

First mkdir [folder], then set hdfs-site.xml then format

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the directory to name(dfs.name.dir) and data (dfs.data.dir) folder is correctly listed in hdfs-site.xml

Answer (score 0):

Formatting namenode worked for me

```
bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searches found the solution
Open terminal
and run

```
stop-all.sh

hadoop namenode -format

start-all.sh
```

Found this answer in one of the community posts on the Model Coding youtube channel
[Post Link](https://www.youtube.com/post/UgkxA3f1S8TSt5EXp1CTN3KUSSMNg8sILqdk)