# NameNode is not formatted

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

After rebooting the servers, hdfs refuses to start and keeps saying :
2016-01-09 17:39:21,117 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.

Data is still there! All seems to be okey, but it keeps failing.
I checked all the solution out there, none helped! I would like avoiding running a namenode format, as I would lose all my data.

Any ideas besides rebuilding?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hadoop - namenode is not starting up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713011/hadoop-namenode-is-not-starting-up)

Comment: That's an initial install. I would lose 5TB of data by formating.

Comment: Have you tried `./bin/hadoop namenode -recover` ?

Comment: Same thing. java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.

Comment: Old question, which I never answered. Turned out that that default data dir was /tmp. And on centOS7, /tmp is cleaned on a schedule. So we lost the data everytime that kicked in. The default to /tmp has long been removed, but is you suffer from this, may want to check out if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

##### just format your namenode by using below command:

$ bin/hdfs namenode -format