# hadoop-1.2.1 namenode is not formatted

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs, namenode

I have installed hadoop 1.2.1 in Ubuntu 16 and configured as below:

core-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>tmpDir/snadikop/hadoopdata</value>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:8021</value>
</property>
```

when I started first time, everything's working fine. but when I restarted the system, and when I tried to start the daemons namenode is not starting.

tried

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

command 
and tried

```
sudo chown snadikop tmpDir/snadikop/hadoopdata
sudo chmod 750 tmpDir/snadikop/hadoopdata
```

where 
   snadikop
is the user.
Still couldn't solve this issue.
please help me with this issue?

Thank you.

Below is my log file

```
2017-03-02 18:07:01,185 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed.
java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:331)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:395)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1488)
2017-03-02 18:07:01,377 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:331)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:395)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1488)

2017-03-02 18:07:01,411 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

and this is what happening in the terminal

```
snadikop@satish-vb:~$ jps
11492 NameNode
11654 DataNode
11863 Jps
11818 SecondaryNameNode
snadikop@satish-vb:~$ jps
11654 DataNode
11880 Jps
11818 SecondaryNameNode
snadikop@satish-vb:~$
```

below are the screenshots locations of 'name' and 'data' folders.
['name' folder path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsZQm.png)
I have doubt regarding this, whether both has to be in same folder or not.

['data' folder path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gmEE.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713011/hadoop-namenode-is-not-starting-up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you have provided to `hadoop.tmp.dir` is a relative path, this would change every time based on the path from where the `start` scripts are invoked. 
This `hadoop.tmp.dir` directory path will be the base path for `dfs.name.dir` and `dfs.data.dir` if they are not explicitly set in `hdfs-site.xml`.

So, if the `tmp.dir` changes, the namenode's name directory changes and thus the `Namenode is not formatted` error.

Add these properties to `hdfs-site.xml` with an absolute non-`tmp` path,

```
<property>
   <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
   <value>/home/username/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
   <value>/home/username/datanode</value>
</property>
```

Then `format` the namenode

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

Also modify the value of `hadoop.tmp.dir` to an absolute path to stop creating `tmp` directories randomly.

Answer (score 0):

format your namenode by using below command:

$ bin/hdfs namenode -format